# Boxing not obvious

Tags: c#, boxing

What I know about boxing is that value type is converted to a reference type and vice-versa. When I did it it was not what I expected:

```
using System;

// ...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object obj1 = 1;
        object obj2 = obj1;

        obj2 = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(obj1);

        Console.Write("Press any key to quit . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

I get the answer 1. Why obj1 value is not changed through obj2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the system executes `obj2 = obj1;` both `obj1` and `obj2` hold references to the same `Int32` object which in turn holds the value `1`.  The like `obj2 = 2;` creates a new `Int32` object which holds the value `2` and stores a reference to it into `obj2`.  The fact that `obj1` used to hold a reference to a different object is irrelevant.  Note that Visual Basic 6 (before the days of .NET) had some quirky semantics where `thing1 = thing2` might attempt to modify the object to which `thing1` holds a reference, and code wanting to store a new reference into `thing1` would need to use `Set thing1 = thing2` but in C# an assignment to an `Object` will overwrite any reference contained therein without regard for what it might previously have contained.